# Gson deserialize Collections

Tags: java, json, gson

New versions of gson have a lot of changes regarding deserialization of Collections. Before we used TypeToken in order to retrieve a List from a Json Array, however TypeToken no longer exists in the library. Are there any examples of what approach to take now??... have been looking at the documentation but it's no clear about this. It suggested implementing the JsonDeserializer interface, and using GsonBuilder... buit again it's not clear. Does anybody has an example of how could we deserialize a collection by using Gson?.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which gson version you are referring to? cause I think all the recent versions of Gson still do have the `TypeToken` in place.

Comment: Yes sorry, you're right... my confusion was because now the contructor is declared as protected in the 2.1 jar, thus the following line of code: Type typeOfCollectionOfFoo = new TypeToken<Collection<Foo>>(){}.getType() no longer works. It was a confusion.

Comment: Ohh Okay. Please answer your question below and mark it as answer. It may help someone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2.1 of google Gson no longer has a public constructor for the TypeToken class, instead we should use one of the static methods provided by it:

IE:

```
List<MyClass> myList= new ArrayList<MyClass>();
Type listType = TypeToken.get(myList.getClass()).getType();
myList= (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

Comment: This is wrong... the listType in this case would be java.util.LinkedHashMap, hence JSON would create a list where each element is an instance of that class, and of course it will generate ClassCastExceptions when iterating the list. What's the correct way to do this? I see no reason why 2.1's version of GSON has a default access constructor...