# Mapping JSON with nested object to GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, confluent-schema-registry

I have a JSON schema class that is auto generate using AVRO. I would like to create a GSON object using this JSON. I try to do so using this code

```
    @Test
    public void parseJson() {

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("/pathto/test.json"));
            ThinEvent thinEvent = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), ThinEvent.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but this results in the following error ... It looks like GSON is looking for a string but the json actually contains a nested object? The ThinEvent object has refService declared as a list.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 74 path $.references[0].refService
```

```
private java.util.List<com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.Reference> references;
```

Here is my JSON, I have replaced some values with XXXX.

```
{
  "eventType": "policy.PolicyPremiumChangedEvent",
  "correlationId": "XXXX",
  "references": [
    {
      "ref": "XXX",
      "refType": "policy_id",
      "refService": {
        "com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.RefService": "policy_service"
      },
      "links": {
        "array": [
          {
            "refUri": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ref": "XXXXXX",
      "refType": "policy_number",
      "refService": {
        "com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.RefService": "policy_service"
      },
      "links": {
        "array": [
          {
            "refUri": "XXXXXX"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ref": "2019-09-28",
      "refType": "policy_tx_effective_date",
      "refService": {
        "com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.RefService": "policy_service"
      },
      "links": {
        "array": [
          {
            "refUri": "XXXXX"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "eventContext": null,
  "Timestamp": 1569574003295,
  "Version": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GSON supports nested objects [check this article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-nested-objects). Just create model that matches the Json (but in Java/Kotlin) and toss it to GSON. [Same with collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989899/gson-deserialize-collections). You can even use List instead of arrays.

You could just get the json file as a complete string and deserialize that as well.

Comment: The model gets created automatically based on the JSON using Avro. so I don't understand why the GSON will not match it

Comment: Interresting I never worked with jsonObject and Gson. Usually retrofit handles things. I just looked at a bit of code where I do do it manually. There I first get an adapter using `Gson.getAdapter(ThinEvent.class)` and then passing the entire string into it. But I just realized that your posted json doesn't start as an object `{ ... }` but right away with values. I just checked and the json I use that with does start with an opening curly brace and ends with a closing one no key before it.

Comment: That is actually a typo is does start and end with a curly brace, editing now

Comment: Okay I just copied you json and typed out the classes and run it with the json as a string and first getting the adapter. It totally worked for me. Couple of things I noticed though. "Timestamp" and "Version" are capitalized. Check if they are in the generated class as this is against the java convention. Same with "com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.RefService" thats not a valid name for a variable but is in the Json. I solved all of these with the @SerializedName("") Gson anotation

Comment: ok so if I use @SerializedName on refService and links variables then this works, my problem though is that these classes are generated so it would have to be a manual change any time the class is generated

Comment: Yes if you get more Json like this send your way that would indeed be problem. Its kinda one of the reason I don't generate my Classes and just write them. You never know what an api will define as a Json model. Anyway see if it helps and I hope you solve your situation without to much work.